# Retrieve data from html to use with SCSS/CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, css-variables, scss-mixins

I have several different templates that use different background images. While I know I can inline the background image or create multiple `classes` to use different background images — I am trying to be creative while making my life easier. Here is what I am aiming for:

1. In the `HTML div` I would like to set a `css var` or `data-attribute` named `background` that holds the image name. So for example:

```
<div class="bg-image" style="--background: 'image-name'"></div>
```

or *(which I don't think is possible)*

```
<div class="bg-image" data-attr="image-name"></div>
```

2. Use that image name to do something like: *Tried the following code and I know this does not work, I'm just seeing if something like this is possible.*

```
// tried this
background-image: url("../images/"var(--background)".jpg");

// also tried this, which I think essentially does the same thing
@mixin form-bg-image($slug) {
  background-image: url("../images/#{$slug}.jpg");
}

.bg-image {
  @include form-bg-image(var(--background));
}
```

Not sure if this is possible without JS, I just think it would be cool to do! Looking for any solutions using `SCSS` and `CSS`.

Comment: You can get close with [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) but unfortunately support for anything other than content is sparse at the moment. With current browsers I believe you'll need some javascript.

Comment: its confusion as how you would do this during runtime? can you recompile scss after HTML is rendered?

Comment: CSS only? Not possible - there's no string concatenation except in the `content` property. You could do this pretty cleanly in SCSS, but it would still transpile to separate lines of CSS for each element/image. Also, your last SCSS example would not be possible because you're trying to apply a CSS variable (determined at browser runtime) into a SCSS mixin (which are resolved in development before CSS compilation).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could have a SCSS dependency file with an array, that would map `[data-attr=""]` elements to `background-image` property. But that is probably not life made easier solution.

What `SCSS -> CSS` compiler do you use? If you wrap it in a grunt task runner, you can scan your html files for specific data attributes and include values into dependency before triggering compilation itself.

Comment: Ah what a great idea!!